# Getting mysterious output in double linked list deletion (c program)

Tags: c

This is my actual code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *pre;
    struct node *next;
};
 void createNode(struct node **head, int data)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    newNode->pre=NULL;
    if(*head==NULL)
    {
        *head=newNode;
        newNode->pre=NULL;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *temp=*head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next=newNode;
        newNode->pre=temp;
    }
}
void insertatBegin(struct node **head,int data)
{
    
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=*head;
    newNode->pre=NULL;
    if(*head!=NULL)
    {
        (*head)->pre=newNode;
    }
    *head=newNode;
}
void display(struct node *head)
{
    int count =0;
    struct node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",temp->data);
        count++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nno of nodes = %d\n",count);
}
void insertatPosition(struct node **head,int data,int pos)
{
    if(pos==0)
    {
        insertatBegin(head,data);
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *newNode;
    newNode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=*head;
    newNode->pre=NULL;
    struct node *temp=*head;
    while(--pos)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newNode->next=temp->next;
        newNode->pre=temp;
        temp->next=newNode;
    }
}
void deleteatLast(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *temp=*head;
    struct node *temp2;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        
    }
    temp2=temp;
    temp=temp->pre;
    temp->next=NULL;
    free(temp2);
    
    return;
}
void deleteatBegin(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *temp=*head;
    *head=(*head)->next;
    (*head)->pre=NULL;
    free(temp);
    return;
}
void deleteatPosition(struct node **head,int pos)
{
    struct node *temp=*head;
    struct node *before,*after;
    int count =0;
    struct node *temp4=*head;
    while(temp4!=NULL)
    {
        
        count++;
        temp4=temp4->next;
    }
    
    if(pos==0)
    {
        deleteatBegin(head);
        return;
    }
    else if(pos==count-1)
    {
        deleteatLast(head);
        return;
    }
else
{
    while(pos!=0)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        pos--;
    }
    before=temp->pre;
    after=temp->next;
    if(before != NULL) 
        { 
        before->next=temp->next;
    }
    if(after != NULL) 
        {
        after->pre=temp->pre;
    }
    free(temp);
    return;
}

}
void main()
{
    struct node *head=NULL;
    createNode(&head,10);
    createNode(&head,20);
    createNode(&head,30);
    insertatBegin(&head,100);
    insertatPosition(&head,25,1);
    display(head);
    deleteatPosition(&head,3);
    display(head);
    deleteatPosition(&head,2);
    display(head);
    return;
    
    
}
```

Here's what I get when I run it.

```
100
25
10
20
30

no of nodes = 5
100
25
10
30

no of nodes = 4
100
30

no of nodes = 2

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.03383 seconds with return value 17
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is the output I got, but I don't want to delete two nodes when I give the position equal to 2.

The output I expecting was

```
100
25
10
20
30

no of nodes = 5
100
25
10
30

no of nodes = 4
100
25
30

no of nodes = 3
```

Comment: Make sure you're compiling in debug mode (`-g` for gcc and clang), and read up on how to use a debugger and/or valgrind.

Comment: Going forward, probably notice that you get a preview of what your post will look like below the editing pane. If your screen is wide enough, you also get a help button at the right of the editor’s menu strip, with a link to the full [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @NAVEENRAJ R, Design thought:  Rather than `NULL` for `.next` and `.pre` to signify the end of the list, consider having the ends point to the other end.  Your loops will then need to check for iterating back to the starting node rather than `NULL`, yet then you will not need any loops when adding/deleting at either end.  Bonus: adding at either end is then the same, its just how `*head` gets updated.  Likewise for deleting.

Comment: I recommend separating the “create a node” functionality from the “insert a node at the beginning of the list” and “insert a node at the end of the list” functions.  It avoids repetition, all else apart.  It also allows for better naming (the functions are “create node and insert at the end” and “create node and insert at the start”, but that's not what the function names indicate).  It also allows you to write “insert node before given node” and “insert node after given node” functions without having to write the allocation code twice more.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not work because of a bug in `insertatPosition()`

```
void insertatPosition(struct node** head, int data, int pos)
{
    if (pos == 0) { insertatBegin(head, data); }
    else
    {
        struct node* newNode;
        newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newNode->data     = data;
        newNode->next     = *head;
        newNode->pre      = NULL;
        struct node* temp = *head;
        while (--pos) { temp = temp->next; }
        newNode->next = temp->next;
        newNode->pre  = temp;
        temp->next    = newNode;
    }
}
```

The code does not adjust the `pre` pointer for the node after position `pos`, if there is such a node. In `main()` when `insertatPosition(&head, 25, 1)` runs everything goes south.

Also if this function is called with a negative `pos` then the `while (--pos)` will run forever...

**Compare with this:**

```
void insert_at(struct node** head, int data, unsigned pos)
{
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        insertatBegin(head, data);
        return;
    }
    struct node* newNode =
        (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data     = data;
    newNode->next     = *head;
    newNode->pre      = NULL;
    struct node* temp = *head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i += 1)
    {
        if (temp == NULL) return;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    // now 'temp' points to the node that will preced this
    // new one
    if (temp->next != NULL) temp->next->pre = newNode;
    newNode->next = temp->next;
    newNode->pre  = temp;
    temp->next    = newNode;
    return;
}
```

This one works. See `if (temp->next != NULL) temp->next->pre = newNode;` and the use of `unsigned` for `pos`

**about the code**

You can make it work this way, but the code is not good. A linked list is a --- possibly empty --- collection of nodes. Then each node points to or contain (your case) a unit of data. There is not even a list in your code, just a node thing. So the list has no *metadata*, not even the obvious `size`. And he use of `node**` is fragile and leads to pointers spread aroud the code...

[Getting mysterious output in double linked list deletion (c program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78091646/getting-mysterious-output-in-double-linked-list-deletion-c-program)